# How To Set Button Below In Layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

hello I want To set Two Button at Bottom
i have Tried So Much but unable To set i want my left right button at bottom 
Here Is My letsbounced

```
<merge
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

<com.example.bounced.card.SwipeFlingAdapterView
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:background="#ffeee9e2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:rotation_degrees="15.5"
    tools:context="com.example.bounced.SlidingMenuActivity" />

<include layout="@layout/buttons"

      />
```

Here Is Buttons layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"

    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here Is My Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RelativeLayout wrapper = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
    // for example
     inflater.inflate(R.layout.letsbounced, wrapper, true);


      Button left=(Button)wrapper.findViewById(R.id.left);
        Button right=(Button)wrapper.findViewById(R.id.right);
        left.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View wrapper) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                left();
            }
        });
 right.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View wrapper) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                right();
            }
        });
```

i m posting Screen Shot Of Layout ..i want to set button at bottom
i have tried so much 
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For aligning views on bottom in Linear layout, just add an empty view with weight="1" so it will take up all the empty space.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/left"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:text="Left"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/right"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:text="Right"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

Or better, use a RelativeLayout and use alignParentBottom = "true"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have changed the code. Now try it. Just add orientation as vertical. And use another horizontal linearLayout for buttons.

Comment: Hey Vipul Thanx 
But Can Please Tell If I want To Change Postion of Button Layout ..Should Be In Center ..and want to give margin

Comment: `android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"` should do that.

Comment: Vipul How To Set Button in center..when I set gravity city ..not working

Comment: Please be clear. You have two buttons. Which one you want centred? Please post an image of what you want and I'll post the layout.

Comment: I want Set Two Button in Center in Horizental .,...
i set android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"  in linearLayout ..
not going on center

Comment: Try using android:center_horizontal = "true"

Comment: android:center_horizontal = "true" not working on Linear Layout

Comment: change width of external RelativeLayout to "match_parent"

Comment: thnxxx Vipul I m Accepting Ur Answer

Answer (score 0):

use `gravity` in linear layout

EXAMPLE:

```
android:gravity="bottom";
```

Comment: Where To Set Gravity Bottom

layoutButton i Set Bottom Not Working

Comment: use this tag in linear layout ... not in buttons .. use it where you wrote `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`

Comment: i putted tag and <include
in Linear layout and orientation vertical

then Not Showing My Button